# Math theory that deals with ordered attr-value items?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

There is partially ordered sets and lattices.
Is there a branch of math that deals with ORDERED Attribute-Value items/objects.
F.e. av-items /see that attrs also can be missing i.e. doors&roof/ :

```
car1:
   wheels : 4
   color  : red
   weight : 1500kg
   doors  : 2

car2:
   wheels : 4
   color  : blue
   weight : 1700kg
   roof   : no
```

The question is : How would you do ORDERING on av-items! so you can also build lattices!

For sets we have Formal Concept Analysis (FCA).
What will be equivalent for AV-sets! if there is such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wheels, color, weight, doors create a 5-tuple (w,c,v,d,r).
The car attributes form a product of sets A = WxCxVxDxR. 
W is the number of wheels ordered by increasing magintude. 
C is the light frequency of the color ordered by increasing magintude.
V is the weight ordered by increasing magintude.
D is the number of doors ordered by increasing magintude. 
R is roof, either 0 for no or 1 or yes ordered 0 < 1.

A can be given the product order 
(a,b,c,d,e) <= (u,v,w,x,y) when
a <= u, b <= v, c <= w, d <= x, e <= y.

Comment: but if f.e. for X1 (b >= v) and X2 (d >= x) then how do you order X1,X2 ... hmm or they are on the same level of the lattice !! non-compararble !!!

Comment: They do not compare.   A linear lattice order would allow comparisons between at to cars.  For that use the dictionary order.